# Android RadioGroup checkedId out of bound

Tags: android, radio-button

I am doing an app in which I must generate checkboxes with certain base values for the initial selected item and then change it's value. Nothing very complicated there.

My problem is when i reset the layout, I create a new RadioGroup with new RadioButtons and a new OnCheckedChangeListener for the RadioGroup. But when I click on a checkbox after resetting the UI, the checkId coming from the listener outputs something too big out of the bound of my RadioGroup.

Here's my code. I won't show the reset part but mainly I call removeAllViews() and then generate the layout again.

```
final RadioGroup optGroup = new RadioGroup(getActivity());
optGroup.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
for(int itemNo = 0; itemNo < cell.getList().countItems(); itemNo++){
    RadioButton rButton = new RadioButton(getActivity());
    rButton.setText(cell.getList().getItem(itemNo).getLabel());
    optGroup.addView(rButton);
    if(cell.getSelectedListItem().getLabel().equals(cell.getList().getItem(itemNo).getLabel())){
        optGroup.check(itemNo+1);
    }
}
optGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        cell.selectListItem(String.valueOf(checkedId));
    }
});
linearLayout.addView(optGroup);
```

When I log my input, before resetting the UI, the output ranges from 1 to 3 (I have 3 checkboxes) and after the reset, it ranges from 4 to 6.

**EDIT** The initial check only works for the first time too, like if the range of the 3 displayed was from 4 to 6 the second time.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the value of cell.getList().countItems() the second time? (after reset). Maybe the list is not cleaned and you're just duplicating the values.

Comment: List is still the same. In fact, the UI I must generate comes from a table of values with different types and everything. So the list is saved in the cell and the only cell's value that can changed is the selectedItem. The rest stays the same. I must have this code work for all the possible tables.

Comment: I think the problem is that you're not setting the id.
Like rButton.setId(itemNo ); But be carefull, itemNo should start at 1 (not 0). Try with that

Comment: I'll try that! And for the 1 instead of 0, I start it a 0 because of the list elements from the cell but I add 1 when checking a radiobutton

Comment: Yes, I mean you cannot use 0 as Id. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Wow! It's working great! I was always told not to "hardcode" an element ID. It's working perfectly! But what difference does it make to put an ID when I reinitialize the elements? You can also answer this and I'll mark it as my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the radioButton ID

```
rButton.setId(itemNo);
```

But make sure not to use 0 as Id.
Since each RadioButton Id must be unique, I guess OS is keeping track of what autogenerated Ids were used (1-3) for the first run. Then after reset, it goes with 4-6, (resumed count from 3)